# How do I generate a histogram from a list of values using matplotlib?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot

so I've been trying to plot a histogram using python with mathplotlib.
So I've got two datasets, basically the heights of a sample of men and women as a list in python, imported off a csv file.

The code that I'm using:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
men=[]
women=[]

with open('women.csv','r') as f:
    r1=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in r1:
        women+=[row[0]]

with open('men.csv','r') as f:
    r2=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in r2:
        men+=[row[0]]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

numBins = 20
ax.hist(men,numBins,color='blue',alpha=0.8)
ax.hist(women,numBins,color='red',alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

and the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//MEME/Users/Meme/Miniconda3/Lib/idlelib/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    ax.hist(men,numBins,color='blue',alpha=0.8)
  File "\\MEME\Users\Meme\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1811, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\\MEME\Users\Meme\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5983, in hist
    raise ValueError("color kwarg must have one color per dataset")
ValueError: color kwarg must have one color per dataset
```

Comment: Here is a tutorial: https://plot.ly/matplotlib/histograms/

Comment: I get the same error using that code.
I believe the issue has something to do with how I imported the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE:assume your files contain multiple lines (comma separated) and the first entry in each line is the height.

The bug is when you append "data" into the `women` and `men` list. `row[0]` is actually a string. Hence matplotlib is confused. I suggest you run this code before plotting (python 2):

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
men=[]
women=[]
import pdb;
with open('women.csv','r') as f:
    r1=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in r1:
        women+=[(row[0])]

with open('men.csv','r') as f:
    r2=csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in r2:
        men+=[(row[0])]


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
print men
print women
#numBins = 20
#ax.hist(men,numBins,color='blue',alpha=0.8)
#ax.hist(women,numBins,color='red',alpha=0.8)
#plt.show()
```

A sample output will be

```
['1','3','3']
['2','3','1']
```

So in the loops, you just do a conversion from string into float or integers e.g. `women += [float(row[0])]` and `men += [float(row[0])]`

Comment: Ah yes, it works perfect now!
Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Good to know it help! Could you please accept my answer by ticking the tick next to it? Thanks heaps. Happy coding